# limits of changing the order of a double integral

Tags: integration, multiple-integral

I've solved this integral $\int_{1}^3 \int_{1-y}^{2-y}x^2y\,dxdy$ which is 3 1/3. Now I'm trying it with different integral order but can't get the limits right. My try was, $\int_{0}^1 \int_{1-x}^{2-x}x^2y\,dydx$.

Comment: And the correct one is $\int_{-2}^{1}\int_{\max\{1-x,1\}}^{\min\{2-x,3\}}x^2y\,dy\,dx$ (not sure what you do it for).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good drawing always helps for these sorts of questions.

[image]

As you can see, the region can be broken up into a triangle between $x=-2$ and $-1$, a pair of lines between $x=-1$ and $0$, and another triangle between $x=0$ and $1$.

So hopefully you can see that

$$\int_1^3 \int_{1-y}^{2-y} x^2y \ \text{d}x \ \text{d}y = \int_{-2}^{-1}\int_{1-x}^3 x^2y \ \text{d}y \ \text{d}x + \int_{-1}^{0} \int_{1-x}^{2-x}x^2y \ \text{d}y \ \text{d}x  + \int_{0}^{1} \int_{1}^{2-x}x^2y \ \text{d}y \ \text{d}x$$

Comment: Cool thx! I drew a graph but forgot the area in the negative area. Now everything’s clear. Cheers.

Comment: Sorry, should it be $$\int_1^3 \int_{1-y}^{2-y} x^2y \ \text{d}x \ \text{d}y = \int_{-2}^{-1}\int_{1-x}^3 x^2y \ \text{d}y \ \text{d}x + \int_{-1}^{0} \int_{1-x}^{2-x}x^2y \ \text{d}y \ \text{d}x  + \int_{0}^{1} \int_{1}^{2-x}x^2y \ \text{d}y \ \text{d}x$$. i.e. the upper limit of dy of the first triangle should be 3?

Comment: Indeed it should, that was silly of me

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try drawing the figure, bounded by
\begin{align}
x=2-y\\
x=1-y\\
y=1\\
y=3
\end{align}

And then set the limits with y as a function of x first.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to draw a graph of the region of integration which is a parallelogram.

You notice that you need three integrals to cover the region if you changed the order of integration.

The x runs from -2 to 1 and you upper and lower limits for y changes on each sub-intervals of length 1.